# NoSql solution for blog data

Tags: nosql

I plan to write a blog style app, wondering what should i be using for storage.

I intend to go with NoSql solution because doing db schema is boring. and I believe I can do most of the functionality with json structured data.

What would be some considerations when design this? Which NoSql technology fits this purpose more?

Roughly looking mongo/couchdb would do, I am hoping to get some experience based advise.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## MongoDB/CouchDB

I guess the easier one of both to start with is MongoDB. It has a bit more a feeling like good-old relational databases, because you can add indexes to columns or call operations like count. In CouchDB as far as I know it you rather use Map-Reduce for all such functions. An index is generated in CouchDB by a so called [views](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views).

Also MongoDB maps the database, table concept roughly to NoSQL (two level access of data), whereas CouchDB only knows one level (database).

```
mytable = Connection().mydatabase.mytable # MongoDB
mytable.save(document)

mydb = couchdb.Server()['mydatabase'] # CouchDB
mydb.save(doc)
```

So I guess CouchDB might be a bit harder to understand at the beginning, because you have to select the documents by some sort of type (or use multiple dbs, but I think an additional attribute `type` is what people use, see this [presentation by David Zuelke page 41](http://www.slideshare.net/Wombert/an-introduction-to-couchdb-ipc11se-20110601).

MongoDB usually works with an API you can include in your programming language (if a library exists, but they exist for most languages). These calls are then sent in binary format to the server. On the other hand, CouchDB uses a REST-API.

## Structure of the data

You can look around for some tutorials around the net. They really often explain something regarding blogs, because blogs are a good example for document oriented datases.

Let’s have a small look ourselves here: You will have a table (or `type` if you use CouchDB) for your posts. Each post can have a text, some tags, a date, comments. The point about document dbs is, that you can store everything aside the document and do save all these relations relational dbs have.

This means, we might model our posts like this:

```
{type: post,
 date: 2012-06-19 22:14:23,
 author: user1462192,
 text: Welcome to my blog,
 comments: [
    {author: Aufziehvogel,
     date: 2012-06-19 22:14:45,
     text: Hello!
    },
    {author: user1462192,
     date: 2012-06-19 22:14:45,
     text: Hello, too!
    }
 ],
 tags: [welcome, new, interesting]
}
```

So that’s what a post could look like.

What you always have to do when developing software. Think about, what data you will save. Think about how it is related. And then as for document-oriented databases you also have to think about how you need to access it.

Sometimes you might have data that should not be saved as a child element of the post itself, because it is too large. Probably you do not only have the name of an author, but also more information like age, registration date, …

Then a user might look like this:

```
{name: Aufziehvogel,
 age: 21,
 registration: 2012-06-19,
 interests: [php, nosql, data-mining, foreign-languages]
}
```

You would not want to attach this data to each blog post, because some of it might change and because it is very large. Instead you would (just like with relational dbs) store a refernce to the user in your post-data. Then you would have to merge authors and blog posts like given in the presentation linked above (p 40-42). This would merge the required author with the blog post.

What you could also do, is saving the authorname and the ID there, to be able to display the name and generate a HTML-link without having to grab the "real" author from the database.

## Validating

What Zuelke also shows is that as for document oriented dbs it’s the application’s task to check whether data is well-formed. In MySQL many tasks can be performed by the database (columns, data type, length, UNIQUE keys), but when using document oriented dbs you have to do it on your own in the application (except that I think MongoDB features stuff like unique keys).

This makes a good code structure important too, so that you do not have to worry about the format of the data at too many places.

I guess there could be said even more, but I hope that’s a first start.

Answer (score 0):

use NoSQL data base provide by app42 .Here is the how to use app42 NoSQL.
http://api.shephertz.com/apis/storage.php